# Identify a Harry Potter fanfic where Voldemort saves Harry and Dumbledore is evil

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I remember reading an incomplete story about an abused Harry being saved by Voldemort and his Death Eaters a couple months back.

It starts off with a narration about how the Slytherins hate the Gryffindors for abusing the first Little (someone with a young mindset like an infant or toddler) to pop up in a long time, then goes on to the rescue, the Malfoy become Harry's parents, Voldemort his grandfather.

And Dumbledore is evil and Voldemort tricks him to re-sort Harry into Slytherin.

There was no romance and I think it was labeled as a family genre, and I believe it was on the fanfiction.net site.

Comment: "the first little to pop up in a long time" - did you miss a word there?

Comment: no, in the story Harry is classified as a little

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (Fanfic) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question)

Comment: Hi! There's a lot of specialized terminology used in fanfiction - not everyone on this site will necessarily understand what a "little" is, for instance. It's good to define this in questions. I'm pretty sure it sometimes refers to someone who has age regression, often in the context of romantic roleplaying, but I can't be sure if that's what it means in the context of the story.

Comment: It's not fanfiction.net, but Archive of Our Own has a listing for that category at https://archiveofourown.org/tags/little!Harry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the story. It is on Archive of Our Own and it's "[To Be Little](https://archiveofourown.org/works/14958221)" by AvengerOfTheGods.

> Harry Potter was severely abused. He is a little and afraid of what will happen when others find out. Snape is the first to care for him as Harry, not as the Boy Who Lived. Add in protective Slytherins, big brother Draco and a sane Dark Lord and you get a family that will stop at nothing to ensure his safety.